# controller/model nil error in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

in my controller I use the following code to send all Articles to the View

```
class Admin::ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  layout 'adminpanel'

  before_action :require_user
  before_action :require_admin

  def index
    @articles = News.all
  end
end
```

But every time I restart my rails server it shows me a nil:nilClass error for some reason.
When I've got this error I have to open my controller, delete a letter in that, rewrite it and save it (Nothing is changed, just rewrote the letter to be able to save) but I don't know why this happens. I've got this

> News.all

in another controller which is on the root route of rails

Here is a screenshot of the error:
[image: error]

Thanks for further help!

Comment: What is the exact error? Nothing here seems wrong. Have a closer look at the stack trace to see where the problem lies.

Comment: Can you show the full stack trace? Look at the file and line number at the top of the stack trace: what code is in that files on that line? What, exactly, is `nil` when it shouldn't be?

Comment: Can I send a screenshot ? Am I allowed to do this ?

Comment: Please explain with the exact error which you are getting

Comment: I've edited my question

Comment: You're certainly allowed to add text, which is preferred over images when it's text-based information.

Comment: I've found out that the error disappears if I only resave any of the files apparently

Answer (score 0):

> undefined method count for nil:NilClass

`@articles` is ***nil***, so is the error. You can replace `<% if @articles.count != 0 %>` to `<% if !@articles.blank? %>` or `<% if @articles.present? %>` which does the same.

Comment: But I cant use ANY @articles.* in the view until i resave the controller... which is a shame

Comment: in the controller it says Articles.all which should set "@articles", but I cant access "@articles" in the view until i re-saved my controller file ( just write a space, delete it and save it again )

Answer (score 0):

Edit: It didn't fix it, just temporary for some reason.

I fixed it! I had the following in my `routes.rb`

```
namespace "admin" do
  resources :articles
  resources :usermanagment
end
```

and I commented the `resources :articles` out and that fixed my error somehow.
Thanks for your help though